# How to display the name of the files that is in the process of analyse in my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have many csv files like this :

```
FRAME_NAME1,LPAR_NAME1,25,1.0,2
FRAME_NAME2,LPAR_NAME2,12,0.8,1
FRAME_NAME1,LPAR_NAME1,25,1.0,2
FRAME_NAME3,LPAR_NAME3,0,null,0
FRAME_NAME3,LPAR_NAME3,0,null,0
FRAME_NAME3,LPAR_NAME3,0,null,0
FRAME_NAME1,LPAR_NAME1,25,1.0,2
FRAME_NAME1,LPAR_NAME1,25,1.0,2
FRAME_NAME2,LPAR_NAME2,25,1.0,2
```

I use this script :

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","

while read FRAME LPARS RAM CPU1 CPU2
do

        if [[ $FRAME != $PREV ]]
        then
                PREV="$FRAME"
echo -e "\e[1;33m$FRAME \
======================\e[0m\n"
fi

echo -e "LPARS : \t$LPARS\n\
RAM : \t$RAM\n\
CPU1 : \t$CPU1\n\
CPU2 : \t$CPU2\n"

done < <(sort "$1")
```

To display those informations like this :

```
FRAME_NAME 1 =======================
LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME1
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX


LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME1
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX


LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME1
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX

LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME1
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX

FRAME_NAME 2 =======================
LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME2
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX

LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME2
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX


FRAME_NAME3 =======================
LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME3
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX

LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME3
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX

LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME3
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX
```

But as I have many csv, I don't know which file is analyse. So when the informations of all my csv are displayed, I would like to display the name of the file to  belongs thoses informations :

Something like this :

```
FILE : my_csv_1.csv


FRAME_NAME 1 =======================
LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME1
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX


LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME1
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX


LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME1
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX

LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME1
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX


FILE : my_csv_2.csv

FRAME_NAME 2 =======================
LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME2
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX

LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME2
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX

FILE : my_csv_3.csv

FRAME_NAME3 =======================
LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME3
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX

LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME3
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX

LPAR_NAME : LPAR_NAME3
RAM : XXXXX
CPU 1 : XXXXX
CPU 2 : XXXXX
```

I have seen the FILENAME variable with awk, but I don't know how to put this variable on my script...

Can you show me how to do this ?

Comment: Your expected output is not clear, please make it more clear in your post and let us know then.

Comment: I've been tried to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your script by the end of the `while` loop reads from a parameter that is `$1` that I assume has to be the file name with which Your script got called.

If so, You can just modify Your script to be like:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","

echo -e "FILENAME : $1\n"

while read FRAME LPARS RAM CPU1 CPU2
do

        if [[ $FRAME != $PREV ]]
        then
                PREV="$FRAME"
echo -e "\e[1;33m$FRAME \
======================\e[0m\n"
fi

echo -e "LPARS : \t$LPARS\n\
RAM : \t$RAM\n\
CPU1 : \t$CPU1\n\
CPU2 : \t$CPU2\n"

done < <(sort "$1")
```

Comment: It's a possibilities, yes. But in the case that I have one file.But I have many files, it's possible to replace " done < <(sort "$1")  " by something like " done < " /var/www/cgi-bin/*.csv " and to display the right file name  above his informations ?

Comment: That's a different question IMO, since Your original question had that script, and could be solved with a `for` loop instead (like `for f in /var/www/cgi-bin/*csv ; do echo $f ; PROCESS_THE_FILE ; done` or with find at the `done` part like `done < `find /PATH -name '*.csv' -exec "echo FILENAME : \{\}" \;`

But these both might fail with too many files as arguments.

Comment: @Makmy : You now worte a script which is able to process 1 file. If you have many files, you will likely invoke the script from within a loop, each iteration passing the respective next file, and hence you also get your filenames printed.

Comment: @Makmy : `done < " /var/www/cgi-bin/*.csv` does not make sense. You can redirect stdin only to a single file.